# Codeigniter Migrations why does migration_path need to be writable?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, migration

Why does migration_path need to be writable? Shouldn't php just need to read the files? I looked at migration code in system folder and cannot find reason.

Here is the comment in application/config/migration.php

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Migrations Path
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Path to your migrations folder.
| Typically, it will be within your application path.
| Also, writing permission is required within the migrations path.
|
*/
$config['migration_path'] = APPPATH.'migrations/';
```

Comment: Well if you are creating a folder on a server and you need to create migration files in it ,how would you be able to write them if the folder wasn't writable.

Comment: I would create these files ahead of time. So when the migration happens; why would CI need to be able to write to it?

Comment: It wouldn't have to be  on a production server and I am guessing some folks do use linux development systems and may create a folder and not set write permissions, hence the comment...